# Migrating Umbraco Sites to Azure

Tags: web-server, azure, web-applications

I have been asked to move all of our internally hosted Umbraco sites over to Azure Web Apps, the problem is I know nothing from the Web side of things (I know my way around SQL and IIS but only from a management point of view). I have looked at Umbraco for some documentation but cant find anything for a server migration.

Am I best pushing back and asked the web developers to handle this or as the SysAdmin, should I be heading up this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umbraco do have a brief page on migration to Azure Web Apps at

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/azure-web-apps

Which should give you some idea of what you have to achieve.

As an Umbraco Dev, I can see the setting up and the ongoing administration of the Azure Web Apps environment being something a SysAdmin would perform, but the actual delivery of running code, be it automated or a manual process would fall under the remit of the backend developer.